# When using the "like" social plugin, can I get the like message to display in the same way as the object preview in the Open Graph dashboard?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I have a music app that I developed using HTML5's canvas. As different songs are selected, I have jquery that dynamically updates the URL in the browser to point to the correct song. I also have jquery that updates fb:like element. By using the debugging tool, I'm able to cache the pages (since my server is able to return correct meta-data for each URL provided).

When I do this and like something on my website, I end up with a message saying "Sami liked a page." with some info underneath.

Next, I use the Open Graph curl commands to add a Recommend action (something I've created) to a given URL from my website. Now, when I like the same url, I end up with a message saying "Sami recommends this link" with some info underneath.

What I'd really like to do is have this message display "Sami recommends a song on website", which is what the message looks like when I look at the preview for my Song object in the Open Graph. Is there any way to do this?

Best,
Sami

EDIT: probably good to note that I'm also getting some extra meta info from the website (such as og:site_name), but that this stuff is not being saved into the Actions portion of my Open Graph (as in I can't view that info using the Open Graph link to view my current Recommendations), though I can see it using the debugger tool.

Comment: If you want to publish a custom action then why do you use "like"?

Comment: The facebook API isn't exactly the most straightforward thing out there. I take it that means this is impossible without using the custom action directly? Even though the custom action is identical to one that facebook already has as a standard (recommend)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The facebook like button "triggers" the most generic action which is the like, you can how ever change the like button to use "recommend" instead of "like".
In the documentation for the [like button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/), in the attributes table you can see the "action" attribute which is:

> the verb to display on the button. Options: 'like', 'recommend'

Also when you "Get Like Button Code" thing you can select Verb to display.

If you want to use your own actions you'll need to define them in the app settings page as explained in the [Define Actions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-actions/) guide.